# "Vorname Name" oder "Name, Vorname" auf Visitenkarten

Tags: usage

Da ich einen für deutsche Ohren kompliziert klingenden Vor- und Nachnamen habe, überlege ich, meinen Namen auf Visitenkarten im Format "Name, Vorname" anzugeben, damit klarer zwischen Vor- und Nachname unterschieden werden kann (insbesondere weil mein Nachname aus 3 einzelnen Wörtern besteht, die man andernfalls schwer vom Vornamen unterscheiden kann).

Ich würde gern wissen, ob dies mit der deutschen "Geschäftsetikette" gut vereinbar ist oder ob man in aller Regel seinen Namen im Format "Vorname Nachname" angeben sollte. (Interessant wäre auch, ob das Format mit Komma auch im Englischen Sprachgebrauch benutzt/verstanden wird).
Eine weitere Option wäre die Angabe im Format "Vorname NACHNAME"–ich tendiere aber zu ersterer Variante, um den Betrachter nicht in Großbuchstaben "anzuschreien".

Comment: Alternativvorschlag: Kapitälchen. _Müller, Johanna_ auf einer Visitenkarte wäre schon arg ungewöhnlich.

Comment: @chirlu, danke für den Alternativvorschlag - sicher auch eine gute Idee! Deinem Kommentar entnehme ich, dass du das Format "Name, Vorname" nicht empfehlen würdest (der Unterschied ist natürlich dass "Johanna Müller" in Deutschland völlig verständlich ist, während ein (ausgedachter) Name wie "Thabit Abd El Fawzi" schon schwieriger zu verstehen ist.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Klarstellung der Begriffe am Beispiel meines eigenen Namens:

> Vorname: **Hubert**
>   Name: **Hubert Schölnast**
>   Nachname: **Schölnast**
>   Familienname: **Schölnast**

Es gibt einen feinen juristischen Unterschied zwischen Familienname und Nachname, diesen will ich hier aber nicht genauer beleuchten. Ich gehe der Einfachheit halber davon aus, dass beide gleich sind.
(Fall es jemanden doch interessiert: Bei eingetragenen Partnerschaften können die beiden Partner zwar denselben Nachnamen annehmen, dann hat aber der Partner, der den Namen ändert, danach de jure keinen Familiennamen mehr. Zumindest ist das in Österreich derzeit so, und vermutlich in Deutschland ebenso.)

Die Bezeichnungen »**Vor**-Name« und »**Nach**-Name« legen schon fest, was davon **vor**her und was **nach**her kommt.

Das wäre daher falsch:

> falsch: **Schölnast Hubert**

Nun ist es aber so, dass man in Verzeichnissen die Namen von Personen nach dem Nachnamen sortiert, und erst bei gleichen Nachnamen nach dem Vornamen. Aus diesem Grund findet man in solchen Verzeichnissen (z.B. in Telefonbüchern) Vor- und Nachname häufig vertauscht. Zur besseren Unterscheidung der Namensbestandteile, wird in solchen Listen dann nach dem Nachnamen ein Komma gesetzt:

> In sortieren Listen: **Schölnast, Hubert**

Das ist aber dann problematisch, wenn der Name aus drei Teilen besteht, wie bei:

> Ludwig van Beethoven
>   Osama bin Laden

Den ersten würde man in einem Telefonbuch als

> Beethoven, Ludwig van

finden, den zweiten als

> Bin Laden, Osama

Tatsächlich ist aber »von« kein Teil des Vornamens (und auch kein zweiter Vorname), »bin« ist kein wirklicher Teil des Nachnamens (sondern bedeutet »Sohn des«)

Von der Auflistung in solchen Verzeichnissen ausgenommen gibt es keinen Grund, die Reihenfolge von Vor- und Nach-Name zu vertauschen. Daher ist zu empfehlen, dies auf Visitenkarten nicht zu tun, und dort die richtige Reihenfolge einzuhalten:

> Auf einer Visitenkarte: **Hubert Schölnast**

Allerdings kann natürlich jeder auf seine Karten schreiben was ihm/ihr einfällt.

---

Am Beispiel einer Fernsehfigur möchte ich noch zeigen, dass jeder Name aus fünf Teilen besteht, von denen bis zu drei leer sein können, die aber eine feste Reihenfolge haben:

> Captain James Tiberius Kirk III
>
> **Captain** = in diesem Fall ein Berufstitel, allgemein ein **Namens-Präfix**
>   **James** = Vorname
>   **Tiberius** = hier: zweiter Vorname, allgemein **Namens-Interfix**
>   **Kirk** = Nachname
>   **III** = hier: Generatiosbezeichnung, allgemein **Namens-Postfix**

Ein zweites Beispiel (mein voller Name, mit akademischen Grad):

> Hubert Schölnast, BSc
>
> = leerer Namens-Präfix
>   **Hubert** = Vorname
>   = leerer Namens-Interfix (ich habe keinen zweiten Vornamen)
>   **Schölnast** = Nachname
>   **, BSc** = **Namens-Postfix**, in meinem Fall ein akademischer Grad, der mit einem Komma vom Familiennamen zu trennen ist.

Alle Teile können aus mehreren Bestandteilen bestehen (z.B. Präfix »Prälat Dr.« oder Postfix »Kaiser von Österreich, König von Ungarn«).

---

Noch ein Nachsatz, auf den ich durch die Antwort von chirlu aufmerksam wurde:

In anderen Sprachen (z.B. Ungarisch) wird der Familienname vor dem Vornamen genannt. Das ist aber auch in einigen deutsche Dialekten der Fall. Dort wo ich aufgewachsen bin (in der Oststeiermark) sagt man nicht:

> Joseph Fink hat ein neues Auto gekauft.

sondern:

> Der Fink Joseph hat ein neues Auto gekauft.

Also: Artikel, Nachname, Vorname

Meinem schon lange verstorbenen Großvater (ein zu Lebzeiten recht bekannter Mundartdichter und Heimatforscher) wäre sogar zuzutrauen gewesen, dass er seinen Namen so auf eine Visitenkarte hätte drucken lassen, wenn er je Wert auf so neumodernes Zeug gelegt hätte:

> Der Schölnast Christian

Aber er wäre damit sicherlich eine Ausnahme geblieben.

Comment: Feste Reihenfolge? "Neuere" akademische Grade wie "B.Sc." und "M.Sc." gehören aber i.A. *hinter* den Namen; sie wären dann ein sechster Bestandteil.

Comment: Zur Regelung in D: Bei der Heirat können die Ehepartner einen der zu diesem Zeitpunkt geführten Nachnamen zum gemeinsamen *Familiennamen* bestimmen, der dann den *Geburtsnamen* oder anderweitig erworbenen Nachnamen (z.B. bei vorheriger Eheschließung und Scheidung) des einen Ehepartners ersetzt. Dieser Familienname wird automatisch zum *Geburtsnamen* etwaiger Kinder. Wurde kein Familienname bestimmt (Unterlassung der Erklärung), führen beide Eheleute ihre Namen weiter. Das erste Kind erhält einen der beiden Nachnamen als Geburtsnamen, diese Wahl gilt dann auch für weitere Kinder.

Comment: Ach ja, natürlich kann die Anzahl der Vornamen >2 sein, ich glaube aktuell ziehen Standesbeamte die Grenze bei 6.

Comment: Die Kommaschreibweise ist übrigens (zumindest in Deutschland) keineswegs nur in Telefonbüchern gebräuchlich. In Klassenlisten und anderen "Teilnehmerlisten" ist sie auch sehr üblich, und dort wird dann durchaus die Form "van Beethoven, Ludwig" verwendet.

Comment: @Stephie: Juristisch exakt wird ein Nachname in D in den meisten Fällen einfach als _Name_ bezeichnet. Der gemeinsame Familienname nach einer Eheschließung heißt _Ehename_ und nach Begründung einer Lebenspartnerschaft _Lebenspartnerschaftsname_. Der Begriff „Familienname“ wird nur ganz selten benutzt, wenn _Name_ uneindeutig wäre (z.B. [§ 47 EGBGB](http://dejure.org/gesetze/EGBGB/47.html)).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Natürlich gehören die Bolognia-Grade hinter den Namen, sind also Teil des Postfixes. Ich habe meinen eigenen Namen hier als Beispiel hinzugefügt. Dass die Komma-Schreibsweise generell in sortieren Listen üblich ist, habe ich ja ohnehin geschrieben, und das Telefonbuch nur als eines von mehren möglichen Beispiel genannt (das meint man üblicherweise mit dem Kürzel »z.B.«), und dass man nach L.v.B. auch unter »van Beethoven, Ludwig« suchen würde, bestätigt meine Aussage, wonach solche Namen Probleme machen wenn man die Reihenfolge nicht einhält.

Comment: @chirlu: Danke für die Ergänzung, ich kenne mich in deutschem Recht gar nicht aus, (und im österreichischen auch nur lückenhaft, aber das Namensrecht hat mich mal interessiert, darum kenne ich da wenigstens Grundzüge)

Comment: Ich halte es für unwahrscheinlich, dass Visitenkarten dem Großvater als "neumodernes Zeug" erschienen sein können, da sie spätestens seit dem 18. Jahrhundert auch im deutschsprachigen Raum verbreitet waren. Als großbürgerlich oder aristokratisch mögen sie hingegen gegolten haben.

Answer (score 6):

Die Visitenkarten die ich habe sind alle *Vorname Nachname*. Das ist die normale Reihenfolge im Deutschen (oder zumindest in Deutschland). Was vielleicht noch ginge, wäre *J. Klopp* statt *Jürgen Klopp* oder so …

Ich als Kunde (persönliche Sichtweise) finde es ansprechender, wenn der Name ausgeschrieben ist, aber was im geschäftlichen Rahmen üblich oder erwünscht ist weiß ich nicht.

Man könnte den Vornamen und Nachnamen auch irgendwie visuell trennen, mit einer leichten Farbänderung zum Beispiel, so dass Fremde, die die Karte lesen, gleich sehen können, wo der Vorname aufhört und der Nachname anfängt.
Es muss nicht unbedingt bunt sein, vielleicht ein etwas hellerer und dunklerer Ton der selben Farbe?
Man könnte auch den Nachnamen etwas größer oder fett drucken …

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Wenn du Zeit hast, nimm eine [tour] der Seite, und bei Fragen, besuche das [help]. Kommentieren wirst du können, sobald du genug Reputation gesammelt hast. Auf ein gutes Zusammenarbeiten!

Comment: Bitte "in fett drucken" zu "fett drucken" ändern. Für einen Edit reicht das nicht :-). Ansonsten +1 für die Antwort was die Formatvorschläge angeht.

Comment: Oh, danke! Hab eigentlich gar nicht vor lange zu bleiben, denn ich bin kein Sprachwissenschaftler. xD Wollte nur etwas zurückgeben für meine Fragen die beantwortet wurden... --- Und Daniel, hättest du ruhig selbst editieren können, irgendwer hat eh schon an meinem Post rumgefummelt. *schulterzuck*

Comment: @Dice Man muss kein Sprachwissenschaftler sein, um hier substanziell beizutragen. Hubert, zum Beispiel, ist Softwareentwickler, wenn ich das richtig mitbekommen habe, ich bin Chemiker. Uns eint nur das *Interesse* – das völlig berufsunabhängig ist. In dem Sinne: Nochmal willkommen und auf hoffentlich lange Zusammenarbeit ;D

Answer (score 4):

Normalerweise steht auf einer Visitenkarte der volle Name mit den Namensteilen in der Reihenfolge, in der man sie auch spricht. Bei deutschen Namen ist das der Vorname gefolgt vom Nachnamen, es kann aber beispielsweise bei ungarischen oder fernöstlichen Namen auch umgekehrt sein. Ein Komma wird allenfalls benutzt, um Zusätze wie nachgestellte akademische Grade oder Adelstitel abzutrennen, sofern man sie nicht in eine eigene Zeile auslagert:

> Johanna Müller, M.A.
>   Charles James Spencer-Churchill, 12<sup>th</sup> Duke of Marlborough

Ein Name in der Form „Nachname, Vorname“ auf einer Visitenkarte, gerade wenn einer der Teilnamen auch noch aus mehreren Bestandteilen besteht und für einen Deutschen nicht unmittelbar als Name erkennbar ist, wäre daher erklärungsbedürftig. Eine Fußnote macht sich auf einer Visitenkarte allerdings nicht gut. :-)

Ich würde daher bei der üblichen Reihenfolge bleiben und den Nachnamen nur typographisch hervorheben, beispielsweise durch Kapitälchen oder durch einen anderen Schriftschnitt (z.B. schmal für den Vornamen und normal für den Nachnamen). Auch das kann aber, da es anders als etwa im Französischen nicht sehr verbreitet ist, zu Rückfragen führen.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis auf ungarische Namen. In Ungarn ist es tatsächlich üblich, den Familienname vor dem Vornamen zu führen (vergleiche: deutsch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Orbán und ungarisch: https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbán_Viktor )