# Ist „FAMILIENNAME Vorname“ akzeptabel auf einer deutschen Visitenkarte, wenn mein Name nicht der westlichen Namensordnung folgt?

Tags: person-names

Mein Name wird normalerweise nicht gemäß der westlichen Namensordnung geschrieben, sondern als *Familienname Vorname*. Es ist mir aber schon öfter passiert, dass ich darauf geachtet habe, in deutschen Briefen oder E-Mails meinen Name als *Vorname Familienname* zu schreiben, und es Leute gab, die erkannt haben, dass laut meiner Muttersprache (Ungarisch) mein Name die umgekehrte Reihenfolge haben sollte, und meinen Namen *nochmal* umgekehrt haben und mich als *Herr [Vorname]* adressiert haben.

Es gab schon [eine Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24017/1224), wo diskutiert wurde, dass *Familienname, Vorname* auf Visitenkarten normalerweise nicht verwendet werden soll. Die Antworten behandeln aber den Fall nicht, wo der Name ursprünglich nicht gemäß der westlichen Namensordnung geschrieben ist.

Kann ich dann *FAMILIENNAME Vorname* auf meine Visitenkarte schreiben? Ist dadurch eindeutig, was mein Familienname ist? Ist es nicht unhöflich, meinen vollen Familiennamen in Großbuchstaben zu schreiben?

Comment: In "Familienname, Vorname" ist es das Komma, das die Reihenfolge klar macht. Bei "FAMILIENNAME Vorname" wüsste ich nicht sofort, was gemeint ist, da diese Form unüblich ist. Wenn ich jemand kennenlerne, bei dem ich weiß, dass in dessen Muttersprache die Reihenfolge anders sein kann, frage ich normalerweise nach. Ich weiß keine gute Lösung für die Visitenkarte.

Comment: Durchgehend Großbuchstaben sieht für „deutsche Augen“ nicht gut aus; wenn, dann Kapitälchen, Fettdruck oder unterschiedliche Schriftbreiten. Das wird aber auch nicht ohne Nachfragen verstanden werden. Ich bin in [meiner Antwort auf die verlinkte Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/24023) darauf schon eingegangen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Vorname Name" oder "Name, Vorname" auf Visitenkarten](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24017/vorname-name-oder-name-vorname-auf-visitenkarten)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast : das habe ich sogar erwähnt, und auch erklärt dass dieser Fall dort nicht behandelt ist.

Comment: @vsz, nicht in der Frage, aber in den Antworten wird auf z.B. Großschreibung und auf ungarische Namen eingegangen.

Comment: man könnte eventuell tricksen, in dem man eine email adresse "vfamilienname@provider" oder eben "familiennamev@provider" (also "mmustermann@..." oder "mustermannm@", aber eben nicht "maxm@..."). Oder man nutzt aus, dass das Ungarische ein paar mehr zeichen und dekorationen hat, als das deutsche und schreibt beides aus also etwa "Paul Erdös / Erdős Pál " (oder andersrum, die verwestlichung des vornamens muss freilich nicht sein)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Persönliche Einschätzung

Ich persönlich würde den Sinn der Großschreibung sofort erfassen und mich über die Hilfe sehr freuen. Als unhöflich empfinde ich das nicht, denn es hilft, „peinliche“ Missverständnisse oder sogar Unhöflichkeiten zu verhindern.

Es gibt für mich im Geschäftsverkehr nichts Schlimmeres, als wenn ich nicht weiß, welcher Teil des Namens meines Gesprächspartners der Familienname ist, oder ich (beim Schreiben einer E-Mail) nicht erkenne, ob der Name männlich oder weiblich ist, und dann die falsche Anrede verwende.

Aber ich bin mir des Problems an sich auch bewusst. Jemand, der noch nie davon gehört hat, dass die Namensreihung auch anders als im Deutschen sein kann, hat möglicherweise Probleme, diese Markierung korrekt einzuordnen.

#### Präzedenz

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/namen) äußert sich nicht zu einer solchen Schreibung, sagt aber, dass Familiennamen nicht der allgemeinen Rechtschreibung unterliegen und nur durch das Standesamt verbindlich geregelt werden.

Die Formatierung des Familiennamens mit Großschreibung kenne ich von behördlichen Dokumenten, auch wenn ich gerade kein Beispiel finde.

Die Wikipedia sagt zudem beispielsweise [über chinesische Namen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinesischer_Name#Umschriften_und_Internationalisierungen):

> In offiziellen Dokumenten und Publikationen kann der Familienname großgeschrieben oder in Kapitälchen gesetzt werden, um Verwechslungen zu vermeiden, zum Beispiel Leslie CHEUNG Kwok Wing.

Ich vermute, der Abschnitt bezieht sich auf chinesische Dokumente. Damit gäbe es zumindest eine Präzedenz, dass die Großschreibungslösung in einem großen Kulturkreis, der das Problem der Familiennamenunklarheit (auch?) kennt, üblich ist. 
 
Und zum Schluss noch etwas zur Großschreibung von Namen allgemein: Zum Beispiel auf dem BRD-Personalausweis ist der Name auch komplett großgeschrieben (allerdings inklusive Vorname(n)).

#### Alternativen

(Warnung: Ich bin kein Designer.) Man könnte – abhängig vom Kontext, für den die Visitenkarten gedacht sind – auch dahin gehen, dass das Design hilft, die Unkonventionalität der angedachten Namensschreibung zu „verstecken“ – z. B., indem alle Informationen in Großschreibung oder Kapitälchen untergebracht werden und der Vorname abgetönt oder dann wieder „normal“ geschrieben wird. Statt einer Hervorhebung des Familiennamens wäre das dann eine In-den-Hintergrund-Stellung der Vornamen.

Wenn Du Dir völlig unsicher bist, könntest Du auch erstmal experimentieren und die Großschreibung in Form von Kapitälchen ausführen, oder stattdessen Fettschrift verwenden und die Wirkung für Dich selbst und im persönlichen Umfeld vergleichen.

Comment: Kapitälchen haben gegenüber reiner Großschreibung den Vorteil, dass man noch erkennt, was Klein- und was Großbuchstaben sind. Ich weiß nicht, ob es im Ungarischen vorkommt, aber generell existieren immerhin Familiennamen, die Binnengroßbuchstaben enthalten.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn man zuerst den Familienname und dann den Vornamen schreibt, wird beides mit einem Komma getrennt. Statt *Peter Bauer* schreibt man *Bauer, Peter*. Besonders wichtig ist das bei nichtdeutchen Namen, damit man weiß, welcher der Vor- und welcher der Familenname ist. *Peter* kann auch ein Familienname sein, also *PETER, Hans* für einen *Hans Peter*.

Comment: Für mich liest sich *Bauer, Peter* als wäre *Peter Bauer* der richtiger Form, nur andersherum geschrieben um den Familiennamen hervorzuheben. Das Komma steht dafür, dass die Reihenfolge geändert wurde, was bei OP nicht der Fall wäre.